# Site links and input fields do not work in iPad

Tags: php, javascript, ipad, codeigniter

Our site's links and buttons do not work when viewed on an iPad. In fact, even clicking (or touching) an input field doesn't bring the field in focus or bring up the iPad keyboard.

The site's been built in PHP (CodeIgniter framework) with nothing too fancy in terms of UI (HTML, CSS, some Javascript and JQuery). No flash.

Any reasons why the site won't work on an iPad properly?

EDIT: I'm sorry if this sounds like a publicity post, that wasn't the intention. The domain name was included in the post but it's in the comments for those that care to visit and give it a try. I still have the error though - visiting on both an iPhone and iPad, the page shows up but the links and input field are not clickable.

Comment: Well, baring the fact that iPads will never match a real computer, we can't really help much without a code or at least a link.

Comment: It doesn't work on my iPhone. Remove the script down the bottom which doesn't do anything and is attached to the inputs click event.

Comment: @PengOne why did you remove his link? @Mike the link is giftbait.com

Comment: @Ben, since it worked fine on my ipad, i assumed it was a publicity post. roll back the edit if you disagree.

Comment: @PengOne fair enough, I can confirm his problem though with my iPhone. I don't believe I have permissions to role back the edit.

Comment: hm, if that is a publicity post (which it sounds like it is), that's an interesting way to set it up

Comment: @PengOne, are you able to click the links and type in the input field on the homepage. Neither works on iPad or iPhone when I test it on my end.

Comment: @Mike, I did include the link but some construed it to be advertising and removed it from the post. I won't repost it, however there isn't any code I can post to explain the error...when you visit the site using iOS (iPhone or iPad) none of the links work.

Comment: Looks like the input question was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469781/ipad-touch-events-on-video-tag

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found it. This is the solution:

Somewhere you've defined on the element where you cannot write:

```
input,select,textarea{ 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
}
```

Change it to:

```
input,select,textarea{
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can only be one of a few things.

1. You have code attached to the mousedown event and are returning false.
2. You have some other JavaScript/Markup errors.

As suggested by "mu is to short" validate your code, [see here](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://www.giftbait.com/)

Remove the script at the bottom, for one it doesn't do anything and two the script tag has no charset attribute. Fix all of the above mentioned errors then post back if it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you're dealing with the native events such as "touchstart" and "touchend" and "touchmove".  If you handle these events you don't get "click" events.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Click only fires if you don't handle the native events.