# iscroll4 based carousel with video

Tags: iphone, html, html5-video, carousel, iscroll4

i've implemented a basic carousel for images with iscroll4. with images everything is (near) perfect.
but when i try to add a video via HTML5 tag, the carousel stops,when i swipe through the video, it scrolls the page to right or left.

i also have this problem with the carousel. my page is a little bit long, so you have to swipe down to see all of the contents. but when you swipe down in the area of carousel, nothing happens.

i only want the carousel to understand swipe-left and right, and the video tag to tap.

is something like this possible?

here is a skeleton of my html.

```
   <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="scroller">
   <ul id="thelist">
   <li><img src="1.png" width="280" /></li>
   <li>
   <video width="280" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" src="x.m4v" poster="x.jpg"  />
   </li>
   <li><img src="2.JPG" width="280" /></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable native video controls by removing video control attribute and use a [custom  video control](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/). 
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3488052/458679