# overlay over dynamically inserted video tag in ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, video, html5-video

I'm currently developing a video player with support for ipad.
It's more of a jquery plugin. It works great on desktop and I even managed to add my custom controls on the ipad.
So far so good.
The problem is that I am creating and inserting dynamically the video element, fact that messes up the ipad a bit. I followed this approach because I found out (after a few long hours) that if you try to wrap (`$.wrap`) the video into a container, the video will crash.
After inserting the video, it acts almost as normal (it is playable and responds to events), but it's position/display properties are messed up: **I can't add any overlay on top of it.** This is an issue, because I want my controls to be able to be displayed on top of the video.

Moreover, the video itself does not respond to the normal `touchmove touchstart touchend` events. After some research, it turns out that if you do not have the default controls turned on, the video captures all the events ([[iPad touch events on <video> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469781/ipad-touch-events-on-video-tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469781/ipad-touch-events-on-video-tag)).
My second problem is that after including the default controls, the video element still seems to ignore my event-handlers.

So, my questions are (both only in Ipad cases):

- have you ever faced this problem, and of course if you did, how did you fix it?
- do only hard-coded video elements trigger events?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some more digging I've found the answer.
Looks like the unmarked answer in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683211/ipad-safari-mobile-seems-to-ignore-z-indexing-position-for-html5-video-elements) holds the key.
So, as [Jaffa The Cake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123395/jaffa-the-cake) (who I ow a bucket of thanks) sais : "You can fix z-index on dynamically created videos by giving the video element -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d", the only workaround is to use the css3 property  **`-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d`**.
This way, one can put an overlay on top of the video which can handle all the events (such as play/pause).

Answer (score 0):

No Ipad can handle dynamic inserted video by Jquery, on the Ipad videos do not respond to touch or move as by default you have to click on a link like play button to trigger the video audio so you can just use Jquery to do this like below

**video**

```
var vid = $('video').get(0);

$('#someselector').click(function() {
 vid.play();

 });
$('#someselector').click(function() {
 vid.stop();

 });
```

**audio**

```
var aud = $('audio').get(0);

$('#someselector').click(function() {
 aud.play();

 });
$('#someselector').click(function() {
 aud.stop();

 });
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, but my video works almost fine.it's only the `z-index` kind of problem. If only i could add an overlay over the video, that could capture all of my "touch" events and act as the play/pause trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to remove the controls using jQuery for all videos like this

```
$('video').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("controls");
});
```

Then, the overlay elements also respond to the corresponding events.
To make the video working again, I've added jquery click event that plays/pause the video:

```
$('video').click(function() {
    $(this).trigger('play');
});
```

Hope that helps.