# jQuery Cycle2 with Youtube videos - swipe or overlaying navigation not working in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, youtube, jquery-cycle2

I have a Youtube video slider using the jQuery Cycle2 plugin. My previous/next arrows are positioned to overlay the videos. And I'm using the jQuery Cycle2 swipe plugin to enable swipe events on touchscreen devices.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/tritterskamp/22cBg/17/

I'm running into two issues on iOS devices.

1. The swipe gesture does not seem to work.
2. Once a video has started playing, the arrows no longer work.

similar to the arrow issue: [Overlay image over a you-tube video is not clickable on I-pod/ I-phone devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545638/overlay-image-over-a-you-tube-video-is-not-clickable-on-i-pod-i-phone-devices?lq=1)

Is the Cycle swipe functionality simply not compatible with Youtube videos?

Any insight would be helpful!

Thanks.

HTML:

```
    <div class="feat-videos">
    <div class="slide">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zlPb8vsvcoM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/o6QubbA4E7A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aP0V9mQTc3g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/g6BmU49XG7w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="cycle-prev">
        &lt;
    </div>

    <div class="cycle-next">
        &gt;
    </div>

    <div class="pager-wrapper">
        <div class="cycle-pager"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// initialize cycle
$('.feat-videos').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 0,
        autoHeight: 'container',
        pager: '> .pager-wrapper .cycle-pager',
        slides: '> .slide',
        swipe: true
    });
});
```